# Is there a way to load the mongodb indexes into the ram on startup?

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I am testing mongo db. I have 3 collections one of which is user collection and has 10 million documents. After indexing the collections it takes about 0,002 ms to query.  Anyway, after restarting the box -ubuntu 12.04 -  the same query takes about 200 ms. That is as if there was no indexes on collections. Is this normal behaviour of mongodb after rebooting the box? Is there a way to load the indexes into the ram on startup?

Comment: That answer talks more about the relationship of RAM usage and indexes, however, to actually load indexes in RAM many people have a script which runs their most frequent queries etc keeping the data in RAM, they run this script maybe once a night

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal MongoDB behaviour is to page data and indexes into memory as used by your application, and leave the decision of what to page out to the operating system's memory management.  The data and indexes typically used by your application are referred to as your "working set".

A `mongod` server that has been running for some time should already have the natural working set in memory, so you shouldn't need (or want) to schedule a nightly data/index reload unless you understand the impact of this.

There are a few different scenarios to "preheat" a server to load appropriate data into memory.

#### NOTE: Use with caution

Generally these approaches should only be used on a "cold server" (i.e. on initial startup) rather than nightly.  You can easily end up swapping out useful data or indexes (and adversely affect performance) if your data & indexes are larger than the memory available to MongoDB.  You can also end up using more memory than necessary by forcing infrequently used data or indexes to be loaded into RAM.

#### Scenario #1: Load all data or indexes for a given collection

In MongoDB 2.2+ you can use the [`touch` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/) to load all data or indexes for a collection from disk into memory.  This can be helpful if you need to work with the full data or indexes for a collection, and have available memory to store these.

#### Scenario #2: Load a subset based on current working set

If you want to load a subset of data which corresponds to your current working set, you could run some queries to "warm up" the database.  The developers at Parse have open sourced some utilities to help provide more specific preheating by sampling and replaying current ops: [Techniques for Warming Up a MongoDB Secondary](http://blog.parse.com/2013/03/07/techniques-for-warming-up-mongodb/).

#### Scenario #3: Run your application's common queries to preload

You can run a set of typical queries for your application, which might load a more realistic working set as compared to "all" data/indexes for a collection or a sample of current operations.